# Unable to uninstall SharePoint 2013 Workflow manager

Tags: workflow, 2013, designer-workflow

I got a problem with my SP2013 Workflows so I decided to uninstall and reinstall it. At first I wanted to disconnect my my server from the farm, but this failed 'cause I can't start the Workflow manager anymore.

So I go for deinstalling it. A PopUp tells me I should run "Remove-WFHost" in PowerShell. This fails because there is a missing certificate at "localmashine\my". After checking this i found out that it is really missing.

Can you give me some tips which certificate I'm missing? Or is there a way to wipe the manager of my system? so I can go for a new installation?

Comment: Are you using the Workflow Manager Configuration Tool and choose 'Leave farm' before uninstalling any of the components?

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps to uninstall workflow manager from the server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193489(v=azure.10).aspx

The programs that need to be uninstalled:

- Workflow Manager 1.0
- Workflow Manager 1.0 Client
- Service Bus 1.0
- Windows Fabric

Answer (score 2):

I found I had to also manually delete the "Workflow Service Application Proxy" service in Central Admin (Application management > manage service applications). It was causing the following error when I would try to access the workflow page for a list item (error from the ULS):

Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it